# android Start Alarm Service with Mobile Clock Time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I want to create Alarm Service that run with mobile clock interval.
For example if mobile time is 20:30:00, Alarm Service repeats, and if time is 20:30:45, Alarm wait and starts from 20:31:00 (what time is not important) and continue on every minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                          SystemClock.currentTimeMillis,
                          1*60*1000, 
                          pendingIntent);
```

More details can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Comment: i test it. it not works and start with mobile minute time